# How can I create a code template in NetBeans 7.1.1 for a log message

Tags: java, templates, netbeans

How can I create a code template in NetBeans 7.1.1 for this:

```
public static void someMethodName(String arg1, Integer arg2) {
    LOG.debug("someMethodName{}, {}", new Object[]{arg1, arg2});
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work :)

```
public static ${ret default="void"} ${mname default="someMethodName"}(${Type1 default="String"} ${var1 default="arg1"}, ${Type2 default="Integer"} ${var2 default="arg2"}) {
    LOG.debug("${mname}{}, {}", new Object[] {${var1}, ${var2}});
    ${cursor}
}
```

But you probably wanted to be able to specify the number of parameters. Unfortunately something like the following:

```
public static ${ret default="void"} ${mname default="someMethodName"}(${args default=""}) {
    LOG.debug("${mname}{}, {}", new Object[] {${args}});
    ${cursor}
}
```

would not work because it would include the type names also in the LOG line:

```
public static void someMethodName(String arg1, int arg2) {
    LOG.debug("someMethodName{}, {}", new Object[]{String arg1, int arg2});

}
```

A workaround that comes to my mind is to use the first solution and provide different code templates for different number of method parameters (e.g. Psm1, Psm2, ...).